# Docker separate containers for node, mongo, how to populate mongo from node container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have two docker containers, one to run my node server, and another to run mongo.

What i'm trying to do is when I install my mongo image, i need it to use node.js to populate mongo with a script i have.

What is the best approach to do this with separate containers for mongo, and node.js?

Currently my thought is that when I create my mongo container, i install node and run my populate script as a `RUN` command.

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a batch job that's part of your Node.js app, you can spin up another container using the image that has that app, just pass a different executable to the `docker run` command.

Here's an example. If you have these two images:

- `yourcorp/node-app`
- `yourcorp/mongo`

Boot up your mongo container: `docker run -d -P yourcorp/mongo`

Run your batch job in a container that will run the script and then quit. For example:
`docker run -e "MONGO_DB=host:port/database" yourcorp/node-app node tasks/seed-database.js`. `tasks/seed-database.js` is just an script you write that lives with your application, but can run independently of a server, that still can `require` other parts of your app and do things (seed the DB) outside of a web request.

Boot your node.js server after the database has been setup:
`docker run -d -P -e "MONGO_DB=host:port/database" yourcorp/node-app supervisor app.js`

Getting exposed ports and environment variables set up the way you want them is up to you. If you give more details, we can give better examples.